# Take accuracy of n high probability output from Keras Lstm model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, softmax

I have a Lstm model for sequence prediction,which is shown here:

```
def create_model(max_sequence_len, total_words):
    input_len = max_sequence_len - 1
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(total_words, 50, input_length=input_len))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=predictors[:1].shape))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(activation='softmax', units = total_words))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], lr=0.01)  
    return model

model_sb = create_model(max_sequence_len, total_words)

history = model_sb.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20 , shuffle = True, validation_split=0.3, )
```

and it works well but I want to take 2 output from my model who are the output with most probability in softmax dense layer.
for take them I can use this code:

```
predicted = model_sb.predict(test_sequence, verbose=1)
```

And then by this code find the first n high probability output:

```
y_sum = predicted.sum(axis=0)
ind = np.argpartition(y_sum, -n)[-n:]
ind[np.argsort(y_sum[ind])]
```

But I need to know the accuracy of my model if the output be one of these n output (with "or" condition)
Is there any package which help me? 
I mean I don't want to evaluate my model with just one most probability output, I want to evaluate accuracy and loss by 2 high probability result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called top-k accuracy, with `k = 2` in your case. Keras already has an implementation of this accuracy:

```
from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy

def my_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)
```

Then you pass this custom metric to your model:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[my_acc])
```